# Including a postscript file into another one?

Tags: include, preprocessor, postscript

I wonder if there a standard way to **include** a **postscript** file into another.
For example, say I have got one file of data generated by a 3rd party program:

```
%!PS
\mydata [ 1 2 3 4 5 6       
(...)
1098098
1098099
] def
```

and I would like to include it into a main PS document

```
%PS
\processData
{
mydata { (..) } foreach
}

(...)

(data.ps) include %<=== ???
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The operator you want is `run`.

> string   **run**   -      
>   execute contents of named file

Unfortunately, `run` is not allowed if the interpreter has the SAFER option set.

**Edit:** Bill Casselman, author of *Mathematical Illustrations" has a Perl script called [psinc](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/graphics/manual/) you can use to "preprocess" yor postscript files, inlining all `(...) run` files.

Comment: One time I compiled the first PS file into an image that I could then include in the second PS file. It was a rather overly complicated process I though, but it did solve the issue we needed solved.

Comment: If it's just a one-off, you can often just insert the text of the other file directly into the first (which is what psinc does). But for things like .eps, you'll often need to set up some "environment" for the subprogram, like scaling or translation.

Comment: @Travis: One time I did a postscript "merge" by just feeding the printed pages back through the printer!

Comment: Haha, that wouldn't have worked for us then because we were shipping off the resulting image as a PDF rather than printing it to a printer. And the process was repeated many times a day. However, if it ever comes up, I am going to first suggest your method. Way less development work ;)

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest meta-solution: use C preprocessor or M4 preprocessor. They are powerful tools and their power may find use in other ways as well, not only file inclusion. Though this was not asked, but use of Makefile will be wise to automate whole workflow. By using a preprocessor and Makefile in combination you can elegantly automate complex inclusions processing and beyond.

**C Preprocessor**

Including a file:

```
#include "other.ps"
```

Commandline for preprocessing:

```
cpp -P main.pps main.ps
```

**M4 Preprocessor**

Including a file:

```
include(other.ps)
```

Commandline for preprocessing:

```
m4 main.pps > main.ps
```

Comment: +1 very interesting. To use the C Preprocessor, I think you'll need another translation step to suppress lines beginning with `#`.

Comment: you don't have to suppress #, preprocessor takes care of this.

Comment: The preprocessor outputs a great many "comment" lines beginning with `#` to indicate line numbers and included files, for the compiler proper to produce debugging symbols. Without special provisions (like removing them, or defining `#` in the PS program to discard the source line), I think this will not work.

Comment: Ah, you mean that. Please check man for -P for cpp.

"-P Inhibit generation of linemarkers in the output from the preprocessor. This might be useful when running the preprocessor on something that is not C code, and will be sent to a program which might be confused by the linemarkers."

I have actually built quite a complex system (an invoice generation) based on cpp.

Answer (score 3):

The standard way to include PostScript is to make the code to be included an EPS (Encapsulated PostScript) file. There are rules on how encapsulated PostScript must be created, and how to include it. See Adobe Tech Note 5002 'Encapsulated PostScript File Format Specification'

Simply executing 'run' on a PostScript file may well work, but it might also cause problems. Many PostScript files (especially those produced by 3rd parties) will include procedure definitions which may clash with your own names, and also the included program may leave the interpreter in a state different from the one it was in when the included file was executed. At the very least you should execute a save/restore pair around the code included via 'run'.

Comment: Good advice in general. But here he needs the data from the file, not a graphical side-effect. So save/restore is what he *should not* do.